# KDE Plasma - Don't blur lock screen?

Tags: kde, kde-plasma-5

A recent(ish) update of KDE Plasma 5 has a new "feature" which blurs the lock screen on mouse or keyboard wake.  Presumably this is so that the on-screen text can be seen against a potentially incompatible background (black text on black BG).  Is there a way to disable this "feature" though?  I'd like to actually see my beautiful lock screen wallpaper, and not have it blurred.  The vast majority of time, I don't need to read the text, I am just typing my password to unlock the screen.

Current version installed is kscreenlocker 5.13.3.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This blur effect was introduced by [this commit](https://github.com/KDE/plasma-workspace/commit/448455c3c937cebc1358dc417b280b0008a4c196) on the `plasma-workspace` project.

For maximum maintainability as future versions are released, I think applying this minimal patch is simplest.  It just makes the fading effect and the clock shadow appear the same (invisible and visible, respectively) in both the "on" and "off" states.

```
--- /run/current-system/sw/share/plasma/look-and-feel/org.kde.breeze.desktop/contents/components/WallpaperFader.qml     1969-12-31 19:00:01.000000000 -0500
+++ WallpaperFader.qml  2018-08-07 10:35:21.004515903 -0400
@@ -113,11 +113,11 @@
             }
             PropertyChanges {
                 target: wallpaperFader
-                factor: 1
+                factor: 0
             }
             PropertyChanges {
                 target: clock.shadow
-                opacity: 0
+                opacity: 1
             }
         },
         State {
```

If you're running [NixOS](https://nixos.org), you can include this change in your build of `plasma-workspace` as shown in [this commit](https://github.com/jerith666/nixpkgs/commit/4070afd19dbb391a4c094e24aa48239e4466bd9e).

Comment: I'm running Gentoo, but I believe that supports local patching without too much fuss.  I'll look into it.  Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: I was actually able to edit this file live, and manually start the lock screen to check the effects of the changes.  Thank you, this will do for a workaround.  I'll see about more "properly" doing a patch on the system package so that my changes are applied more gracefully when the package is updated by the package manager.

Comment: Here's the Portage patch I made that worked for me.  Thanks again, Matt.  https://gist.github.com/Pistos/bdfa5c19a530e8038b44cf9c6a714308